# InfoBar only shown on window change

Tags: c, gtk3

Why is the GtkInfoBar only visible if I change the window (focus)?

**Hit the F5 key to get the InfoBar visible. Close the InfoBar and hit F5 again.**

On my debian 8 (Gnome 3.20) system the InfoBar is only visible the first time, from the second time on it's only visible if I change the focus of the application window.

```
// gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o info_bar infobar_nonglade.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>

// Callback to close the window with Esc key
static gboolean check_escape(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data) {
        if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Escape) {
                gtk_main_quit();
                return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
}

static gboolean on_key_f5(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer infobar) {
        if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_F5) {
                gtk_widget_set_visible(infobar, !(gtk_widget_get_visible(infobar)));
                return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        GtkWidget *button, *content_area, *infobar, *message_label, *vbox, *window;
        window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
        infobar = gtk_info_bar_new();
        button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("OK");
        gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 1024, 600);
        gtk_widget_set_no_show_all (infobar, TRUE);
        gtk_info_bar_add_button (GTK_INFO_BAR (infobar),
                                 "OK",
                                 GTK_RESPONSE_OK);
        g_signal_connect (infobar, "response", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_hide), NULL);
        gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);
        gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), infobar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
        gtk_widget_show_all (vbox);
        // Connect callback to close the window with the Esc key
        g_signal_connect (window, "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (check_escape), NULL);
        g_signal_connect (window, "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (on_key_f5), infobar);
        gtk_widget_show_all (window);
        gtk_main();

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an old well known bug :(

Simple solution is to disable animations. I can live with that perfectly fine.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        // Fix InfoBar Bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=710888
        g_object_set (gtk_settings_get_default (), "gtk-enable-animations", FALSE, NULL);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not test it on my machine, but you can try:

```
gtk_widget_set_visible(infobar, !(gtk_widget_get_visible(infobar)));
```

instead of

```
gtk_widget_set_no_show_all (infobar, FALSE);
gtk_widget_show_all (infobar);
```

Also, why are you invalidating the event returning `TRUE` on `gboolean on_key_f5`?

Comment: Same behavior, sorry. But I update my question with your snippet. I like it.